# Неправильная вложенность меню

Tags: php, битрикс

Подскажите, как поставить правильную вложенность в меню.У меня получается последовательность элементов

```
<ul>
      <li><a>text1</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
      <li><a>text2</a></li>
</ul>
```

а мне нужна такая последовательность

```
<ul>
     <li><a>text1</a></li>
     <ul>
         <li><a>text2</a></li>
         <li><a>text3</a></li> 
     </ul>
</ul>
```

нужно поменять условие в коде,помогите поправить

```
<?if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>
<? 
//var_dump($arResult);
//echo "<pre>";print_r($arResult);echo "</pre>";?>
<div id="t_menu">
<?for($i=0; $i < count($arResult); $i++)
    {   if($arResult[$i]["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1)
            { //echo'<pre>';var_dump($arResult[$i]["SELECTED"]); echo'</pre>';
                ?><div class="itm">
                    <?if($arResult[$i]["SELECTED"])
                        {?><div class="itm_act select"><?}
                        else
                        {?><div class="itm_act"><?}?>
                        <a class="vinetka" href="<?=$arResult[$i]["LINK"]?>"><?=$arResult[$i]["TEXT"]?></a>
                    </div>
                <?if($arResult[$i+1]["DEPTH_LEVEL"] > 1 || $arResult[$i+1]["PARAMS"]["DEPTH_LEVEL"] > 2)
                    {?><ul class="sub_top_men">
                        <?while($arResult[$i+1]["DEPTH_LEVEL"] > 1 )
                            {?>                                                                                                           
                <?if( $arResult[$i+1]["PARAMS"]["DEPTH_LEVEL"] > 2)
                    {?><ul class="sub_top_men3"> <?}?>
                        <li><a class="s_itm" href="<?=$arResult[$i+1]["LINK"]?>"><?=$arResult[$i+1]["TEXT"]?></a></li>
                <?if( $arResult[$i+1]["PARAMS"]["DEPTH_LEVEL"] > 2)
                    {?></ul> <?}?>
                            <?  $i++;
                            }?>     
                        </ul>
                    <?}?>
                </div>
                <?if($i+1 < count($arResult))
                    {?> <span class="line">|</span>
                    <?}?>
            <?}
    }?>
    <a class="link-rss" href="/press/subscribe.php">&nbsp;</a>
    <br class="clearfloat" />
</div>
<div class="clearfloat"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас в этом участке кода требуется изменение

```
<?while($arResult[$i+1]["DEPTH_LEVEL"] > 1 )
 {?>
    <?if( $arResult[$i+1]["PARAMS"]["DEPTH_LEVEL"] > 2)
       {?><ul class="sub_top_men3"> <?}?>
          <li><a class="s_itm" href="<?=$arResult[$i+1]["LINK"]?>"><?=$arResult[$i+1]["TEXT"]?></a></li>
          <?if( $arResult[$i+1]["PARAMS"]["DEPTH_LEVEL"] > 2)
             {?></ul> <?}?>
          <?  $i++;
       }?>
```

Здесь не проверяется предыдущая глубина и потому выводится подменю на каждую строку, как и закрывается в каждой строке, вместо того, чтобы подменю печаталось именно при увеличении глубины, и закрывалось только при уменьшении глубины.
Как вариант так:

```
if($arr[i+1]['params']['deph'] > $arr[i]['params']['deph']) 
{ 
   echo '<ul class="sub_top_menu3">';
}
echo '<li><a class="s_itm" .... </a></li>';
i++;
if($arr[i+1]['params']['deph'] < $arr[i]['params']['deph']) 
{
   echo '</ul>';
}
```

Возможны варианты с использованием переменных или иного способа контроля изменения вложенности.

Comment: https://ideone.com/brk2Ep чего то не работает((

Comment: А что получается?

Comment: можете показать код?

Comment: код я ввиде ссылочки прислал посмотрите выше

Comment: посмотрите мой код, надо поднять выше i++

Comment: спасибо громадное

Comment: Был рад помочь.

Comment: взгляните пожалста на новый код отвечающий за вызов меню https://ideone.com/GjG1Xc ,как в данном случае получить такой вариант 
<ul>
     <li><a>text1</a></li>
     <ul>
         <li><a>text2</a></li>
         <li><a>text3</a></li> 
     </ul>
</ul>

Comment: Я так понимаю, что достаточно указать для первого пункта в массиве глубину 2 а для text2 и text3 - 3.

Comment: Небольшая поправка... В вашем алгоритме '<li> ... <ul>' выводится в блоке проверки '[IS_PARENT]', собственно там и стоит вносить поправку, как и исключить закрывающий '</li>' в конце цикла при проверке уровня.