# Горизонтальное выпадающие меню Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Пытаюсь реализовать меню следующего вида

```
<ul>
 <li>
    Text
    <ul>
        <li>h1</li>
        <li>h2</li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Text2</li>
</ul>
```

Для этого пишу

```html
<?if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>
<ul class="leftmenu">
<?
$previousLevel = 0;
foreach($arResult as $arItem):?>

 <?if ($previousLevel && $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] < $previousLevel):?>
  <?=str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel - $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"]));?>
 <?endif?>

 <?if ($arItem["IS_PARENT"]):?>

  <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1):?>
   <li><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>root-item-selected<?else:?>root-item<?endif?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
    <ul>
  <?else:?>
   <li<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?> class="item-selected"<?endif?>><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="parent"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
    <ul>
  <?endif?>

 <?else:?>

  <?if ($arItem["PERMISSION"] > "D"):?>

   <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1):?>
    <li><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>root-item-selected<?else:?>root-item<?endif?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
   <?else:?>
    <li<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?> class="item-selected"<?endif?>><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
   <?endif?>

  <?else:?>

   <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1):?>
    <li><a href="" class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>root-item-selected<?else:?>root-item<?endif?>" title="<?=GetMessage("MENU_ITEM_ACCESS_DENIED")?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
   <?else:?>
    <li><a href="" class="denied" title="<?=GetMessage("MENU_ITEM_ACCESS_DENIED")?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
   <?endif?>

  <?endif?>

 <?endif?>

 <?$previousLevel = $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"];?>

<?endforeach?>

<?if ($previousLevel > 1)://close last item tags?>
 <?=str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel-1) );?>
<?endif?>

</ul>
```

Но получается, в результате

```
<ul>
  <li>1<li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Как исправить?Подскажите пожалста!

Comment: по моему <?=str_repeat("</ul></li>" надо исправить на <?=str_repeat("</li></ul>" 
несмотря что у вас даже открывающего тега <li> нету
рас код написан правильно,а по моему в $arItem["TEXT"] лежит цифра,надо смотреть почему

Comment: Это же стандартный шаблон меню "horizontal_multilevel" да? Я не вижу изменений. Если да, то он должен работать так как нужно по умолчанию. Возможно проблема с самим меню? Можно посмотреть как объявляется меню и подменю?

Comment: Взгляните на это обсуждение http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537008/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e/537034?noredirect=1#comment676363_537034 в частности на пример кода отсюда: https://ideone.com/GjG1Xc - там как раз ваш случай показан